# Eclipse doesn't show infrared5 server

Tags: eclipse, red5

Im using `windows 8 64-bit OS`. I'm using `Eclipse Indigo 32-bit` for `red5`. I've installed `red5` plugins. I wanted to build a dynamic web project and need `Infrared5` server as New Server Runtime Environment. But I cannot find `Infrared5` option when I click new Runtime.

What is the matter? Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: you need to install the Red5 Plugin http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EedQyafOIm0

Comment: I'd done that, but the problem was when I bring in the flash-builder plugin, somehow Infrared5 would disappear. I'm through it anyway.